# SOAP Attachment from .NET 3.5 to PHP web service

Tags: .net, php, .net-3.5, soap

We've got a PHP web service which we need to send a file from a .NET 3.5 web app.

The PHP team has stated that we need to provide the file in the form of a SOAP attachment, but we can't find a way from which we can do that in .NET.

All reference examples that we've been able to come across refer to using the DIME, but that's not supported in .NET 3.5/ VS 2008 (or so it seems).

Any idea how to send the SOAP attachment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Internet_Message_Encapsulation):

> Direct Internet Message Encapsulation (DIME) is a Microsoft-proposed internet 
>   standard for the transfer of binary and other encapsulated data over SOAP."

This is totally unrelated to SOAP with Attachments or XOP/MOTM, which supercedes it:

> Microsoft now describes it as "superseded by the SOAP Message Transmission Optimization 
>   Mechanism (MTOM) [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951268.aspx)

From what I can tell, DIME was supposed to be a simplified version of MIME, which is what Soap With Attachments uses. So DIME was just a typical technology of the "Embrace, Extend, Extinguish" kind, which appears to be dead anyways.

The PHP 5 SOAP extension does not support SwA, as said in this [post](http://www.nabble.com/SOAP-and-attachment-td15075220.html). [WSF/PHP](http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/php/features) Supports MTOM.

To implement MTOM in .NET, look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/MTOMWebServices.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Add Attachments to a SOAP Message by Using DIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824597.aspx)

Comment: From what we've worked out this doesn't work with VS 2008/ .NET 3.5